# What exactly does Google Maps JavaScript API 3 StreetViewPanoramaOptions disableDoubleClickZoom do?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, code-documentation

The documentation for Google Maps StreetViewPanoramaOptions lists [disableDoubleClickZoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view#StreetViewPanoramaOptions.disableDoubleClickZoom) as an option.

I am using API version 3.48.  I have researched and tried a bunch of different options on a google map locally and online to try and figure out what this option does but cannot find anything.

What exactly does this option do?  Is it still a valid option?  Are there any live examples?

The default value is `true` meaning double click zoom should be disabled by default.  This makes sense as double clicking in most cases navigates the street view to a new location.  Disabling the navigation, setting the value to false, then double clicking yields no results.  Setting it to true makes no difference as well.

I found a [really old article](https://maps.googleblog.com/2009/06/introducing-smart-navigation-in-street.html) that talks about double clicking to zoom.  It states:

> Sometimes the pancake shows a little magnifying glass in the bottom right to indicate that double clicking will zoom in on the current image rather than transport you to a closer location.

I cannot find any place in street view that shows such a magnifying class.  If there is such a place a latitude and longitude would be helpful to test it out.

[This old article](https://www.searchenginewatch.com/2009/07/26/google-maps-provides-street-view-zoom-via-panoramio-pics/) also mentions something similar showing images that can be double clicked to see images of an object (such as the Eiffel Tower) "zoomed in".  The UI shown in this example is very different from what is available now.

These articles are from 2009.  I am wondering if this option is a legacy option that no longer works.

It is important to note that [this (street view) disableDoubleClickZoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view#StreetViewPanoramaOptions.disableDoubleClickZoom) is not the same as the [mapOptions disableDoubleClickZoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.disableDoubleClickZoom).

[Example with value set to `false`.](https://jsfiddle.net/urgno10q/)

Comment: Would it be possible for you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @rafon https://jsfiddle.net/urgno10q/

Comment: @codelin, it appears that a sample code has already been included in your description. Would you mind filing a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207)?